# Office 365 JavaScript API - get list of custom properties and values

Tags: office365, office-js, office365api, custom-properties

I tried going through the documentation and failed to find any information about accessing the custom properties of an Office 365 document. I want to to be able to access these properties to perform certain actions on them from my Office 365 plug-in.

[image: Custom document properties]

I found this method
[But it only seems to return the file Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.document?view=word-js-preview#getfilepropertiesasync-callback-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use `customProperties`, which is `Excel.CustomPropertyCollection` class

Here is a sample code:

```
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let docProperties = context.workbook.properties;

    docProperties.load(
      "author, lastAuthor, revisionNumber, title, subject, keywords, comments, category, manager, company, creationDate"
    );

    await context.sync();

    console.log("Author: " + docProperties.author);
    console.log("Title: " + docProperties.title);
    console.log("Subject: " + docProperties.subject);

  });
```

The document can be found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.documentproperties?view=excel-js-preview